How to window a dataset with categorical and numerical data for LSTM model?
I have a dataset with 3 columns: Timestamp (string), Inverter_Key (string) (21 inverters for my case), energy (integer), temperature ( integer). I try to create LSTM model to predict energy and temperature of each inverter. To enhance the speed of model, instead get the input shape (96,66). I combined the dataset for train and test to have dataset as (96,4). However, the prediction is not match the actual data when tested. I believed it happen due to the windowing because I already check for outlier and correlation relationship. The relationship is show Energy and Temperature have linear relationship as 0.78 and non linear is 0.8. I also scale my energy data to get smaller. Thus, it must be the way I window the data.
For the data, energy and temperature will be recorded every 15 minutes. For example
Timestamp       , Inverter_Key , Energy, Temperature
12/12/2022 10:15, KU           ,  2    , 22
12/12/2022 10:15, KS           ,  4    , 22
12/12/2022 10:30, KU           ,  4    , 21
12/12/2022 10:30, KS           ,  5    , 21

I have use labelling technique to label time, encode hot code to label Inverter Key as integer as well.
Here is how I am windowing :
def windowed_dataset(data, window_size=96, batch_size=128, shuffle_buffer=1000):
    
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data) 
    dataset = dataset.window(window_size + 1, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size + 1))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1]))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size,drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    
    return dataset

How i create model and fit the model:
def create_M_LSTM_model():
    model_m_lstm = tf.keras.models.Sequential([


        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,return_sequences=True,input_shape = input_data_shape),
        #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32,return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16,return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(6),
    ])
    return model_m_lstm


def create_model_M_LSTM():
    tf.random.set_seed(51)  # Set a seed for reproducibility

    model_create = create_M_LSTM_model()  # Create the model
    model_create.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),  # Loss function
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),  # Optimizer
        metrics=["mae"]  # Metric
    )
    return model_create

# Create and summarize the model
model_create_m_lstm = create_model_M_LSTM()

# Print model summary
model_create_m_lstm.summary()

is_train = True
if is_train:
   model_create_m_lstm.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20)

How can I window train dataset which contain both categorical and numerical data? The expected dataset is that when I extract data of KU inverter out of the prediction is will match with the data of KU inverter  of test dataset.
